# Visual Studio Hotkey - Go up one folder

Tags: visual-studio-2012, hotkeys, visual-studio-2013

In Windows Explorer, one can press Alt + Up Arrow to "Go up one folder"

When developing in Visual Studio, all too often I want to find a relative path from a file to some location higher in the hierarchy. Unfortunately, Alt + Up doesn't work in Visual Studio to travel up the folder hierarchy. Is there a different hotkey or a way to set one to do this inside the IDE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a built in shortcut, but you can create your own: Go to Tools | Options | Environment | Keyboard and look for the right command for going up to the parent directory. Then click the Press Shortcut Keys box and press your new shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

Old post but I answer anyways.

- One layer down (into folder): Enter
- One layer up:                 Backspace
- Select file:                  Arrow Keys
- Select multiple files:        Arrow Keys + Shift / Ctrl
- Delete file:                  Delete
- Unselect files:               Esc